# How to store values of an array inside a table in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, loops

I have two tables named "imports" and "import_details". Inside the "imports" table are log files that have been uploaded using carrierwave. I have a method that reads the log file and extracts the data that I need from each entry (I used regex for this). My regex expression has a total of 12 capture groups, and each capture group is a value that I want to store inside the "import_details" table.

My problem is I don't know how to iterate through each of them and store them in each row after the regex expression has reached the 12th capture group.

My create_imports.rb:

```
class CreateImports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :imports do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :attachment

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

create_import_details.rb:

```
class CreateImportDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :import_details do |t|
      t.string :controller
      t.string :controllermethod
      t.string :ipaddress
      t.datetime :datetime
      t.string :methodname
      t.string :sessionid
      t.string :cycletime
      t.string :restimeview
      t.string :restimerecord
      t.integer :statuscode
      t.string :statusname
      t.string :urladdress

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My method for reading a log file:

```
def processimport
    path = Dir.glob('/sample/file/path/'@import = Import.find(params[:id])'/*.log').first
    regex = /sampleregexexpression/

    samplefile = File.open(path)
    string = File.read(samplefile)

    string.scan(regex).each do|x|
      puts x
    end 
  end
```

What my processimport method currently does is only to print out the values of each capture group that my regex gets. Any idea how to loop through them and store in a database?

A sample response of

```
string.scan(regex).each do|x|
  puts x
end
```

looks like this:

```
SampleController
create
10.910.992.227
2020-12-01 12:00:00
POST
12mnd9adkmc82js9akjnas98sdv3
0.12995 (7 reqs/sec)
0.00027 (0%)
0.09836 (75%)
201
Created
[https://www.soap.com/api/sample.xml]
AnotherController
index
888.12.445.247
2020-12-01 12:00:00
GET
ertye73do928hxksmsu2edjejend783k
0.00905 (110 reqs/sec)
0.00007 (0%)
0.00281 (31%)
200
OK
[https://www.samplecloud.com/api/anothersample.xml?sample_id=9002&after=2020-12-01 12:00:00Z&page=1]
ExampleController
index
838.33.55.776
2020-12-01 12:00:00
GET
7282849jfjdkdo2a29snxmmjscnssdn8
0.23466 (4 reqs/sec)
0.15961 (68%)
0.06614 (28%)
200
OK
[https://customer.example.com/en/example]
ThisIsAController
show
992.334.556.1
2020-12-01 12:00:00
GET
jasd7839njsdnlkal3898259adansdn
0.26166 (3 reqs/sec)
0.13863 (52%)
0.11492 (43%)
200
OK
[https://www.sample.com/en/soap/shampoo]
```

In this example, there are 4 log file entries inside one log file, each of them start with the Controller (capture group 1) and end with URL address (capture group 12). The goal is to store in the database table the first set of capture groups in one row, the second set in the next row, and so on.

Comment: can you provide sample response of this `string.scan(regex)`? So, that it would be clear to answer you're question.

Comment: if you were able to push each response into array of objects like this `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}]` then you can easily loop through them and store into `import_details`. As the response is not structured

Answer (score 0):

I would create a hash of the values you want in the loop:

```
    my_hash = {}
    string.scan(regex).each do|x|
      my_hash[:key] = x
    end
```

as long as each key matches exactly with a column in your table you can call

```
ImportDetails.create(my_hash)
```

Comment: i have a doubt! How can you match keys to those values? It only works if the response is structured right?

Comment: @UdAY C.N.N didn't give any specific response example so I was simply guiding them down a path with the little knowledge we have

Comment: @UdAY for instance I want to store the value of my first capture group in the column titled "controller", the value for that would be "x[0]". I figured this out while I was playing around with my code last week.

Comment: @C.N.N so for every `capture group` does the `regex` changes?

Comment: @UdAY yes, you got it :) As you can imagine, there are 12 capture groups, so it's a pretty long regex expression, but I've tested it lots of times and it works in every try. The log files to be uploaded all come from one application, so I especially tailored the regex expression to match the pattern of this applications log files.

Comment: @C.N.N can you provide the sample response for this `string.scan(regex)`?